# PostgreSQL: SQL script to get a list of all foreign key references to a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, information-schema

I have a table, `breeds` with a primary key of `breed_name` and would like to get a list of all tables, columns and constraints that reference `breeds` regardless of column referenced in `breeds`. If there is another table, `cats` and that has a constraint as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE cats 
(
    cat_name  text,
    cat_breed text,

    CONSTRAINT cat_breed_name 
        FOREIGN KEY (cat_breed) REFERENCES breeds(breed_name)
)
```

I should get back a row like the following:

```
base_table     base_col    referencing_table   referencing_col  constraint_sql
breeds         breed_name  cats                cat_breed        CONSTRAINT cat_breed_name FOREIGN KEY (cat_breed) REFERENCES breeds(breed_name)
```

Non-primary key references should also be listed and it should handle compound keys.

Comment: starting `psql -E` and then running `\d breeds` will show you a query for that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe This is for a Python script using psycopg. I have to do it in SQL, not `psql`.

Comment: Sure, but this will give you the query you can use in your Python program.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't think that's correct. You can't use psql special commands in psycopg. Also \d does not produce any SQL statements.

Comment: Try starting `psql -E`, run `\d breeds` and look at the *whole* output. Or don't if you don't believe me.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It's not about not believing you. Read my second sentence: I need the Python app to do this for 60 tables...my original question was clear: I need the SQL script, not a Postgres command.

Comment: I did try it. It does not answer the question.

Comment: Then you didn't look at the *whole* output.

Comment: You are not reading the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Please read the ANSI SQL standard because your comments indicate you don't understand it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `psycopg2.connect().cursor().execute(r'\d table_name')` is not possible.

Comment: I can see that you are annoyed at me. If you run `\d breeds` in `psql -E`, you will get a lot of additional queries in the output. Look at the ones on `pg_constraint`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to JOIN `pg_constraint` to `pg_attribute` and un nest the column arrays (could be compound keys) to get the referenced column name in the base table.
You have to use `pg_class` to get the table names.
`pg_get_constraintdef` gives you the actual SQL line that is used to create the constraint.

```
SELECT (select  r.relname from pg_class r where r.oid = c.confrelid) as base_table,
       a.attname as base_col,
       (select r.relname from pg_class r where r.oid = c.conrelid) as referencing_table,
       UNNEST((select array_agg(attname) from pg_attribute where attrelid = c.conrelid and array[attnum] <@ c.conkey)) as referencing_col,
       pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid) contraint_sql
  FROM pg_constraint c join pg_attribute a on c.confrelid=a.attrelid and a.attnum = ANY(confkey)
 WHERE c.confrelid = (select oid from pg_class where relname = 'breeds')
   AND c.confrelid!=c.conrelid;
```